# Zero space between bars in pgfplots bar graph

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar graph with the bars touching, like in a histogram, using pgfplots. This is basically what I'm aiming for:
[image: Bar graph with bars touching]

That plot is generated with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
        \addplot[fill=gray, bar width=41] plot coordinates
            {(1,160) (2,-50) (3,-98) (4,95) (5,270)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem with my code is that the value for the `bar width` key was found by trial and error, doesn't place the bars exactly right, and needs to be changed if I want to change the size of the graph.

I was expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar, width=\textwidth,]
        \addplot[fill=gray, bar width=0.2\textwidth] plot coordinates
            {(1,160) (2,-50) (3,-98) (4,95) (5,270)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but that makes the bars too wide: 
[image: Bars too wide]

Ideally I'd like a solution that scales with changes in the size of the graph.

Comment: Instead of `ybar` try `ybar interval`. Is that a reasonable result for you?

Comment: That gets me pretty close. I can easily remove the vertical grid lines by adding the option key `xmajorgrids=false`, but I still get ticks _between_ the numbers on the x-axis, and I can't figure out how to get rid of these without losing the numbers too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Percusse's suggestion of using `ybar interval` is a good idea, as this will give you perfectly aligned bars without gaps between them.

Note that you will have to provide a dummy data point at the end of your data, as the `ybar interval` style needs to know how wide the last bar has to be. In this example, you could add a coordinate like `(6,0)` (the y component doesn't matter here, only the x component is used).

To get tick marks and labels that are centred with respect to the bars, you'll have to use a bit of trickery: The `ybar interval` bars will go from `1` to `2`, and `2` to `3`, so their centres won't be round values. To fix this, we can use an `x filter/.code` to shift the bars to the left by `0.5`. By default, the `ybar interval` key sets `xtick=data`, so the start of each bar would be used for the tick positions. This is not what we want in this case, so we'll have to switch it off using `xtick={}`. This turns the normal tick placement mechanism back on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        enlarge x limits=false,
        ybar interval,
        x tick label as interval=false,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},
        xtick={},
        xmajorgrids=false
    ]
        \addplot[fill=gray] plot coordinates
            {(1,160) (2,-50) (3,-98) (4,95) (5,270) (6,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to center the error bars as well, like plain `ybar` does? (Should I ask this as a separate question?)