# Pgfplots: ybar without gap and middle alignment on data

Tags: pgfplots, plot, bar-chart

I would like to represent an approximation to a function. I use `ybar` for the approximation with a certain sample size. However, using the standard `ybar` I get a gap between the single bars that I do not want. On the other hand, if I use `ybar interval` as proposed [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57028/zero-space-between-bars-in-pgfplots-bar-graph) the bars are shifted to the right.

How can I get a combination of both, zero gap and middle alignement of the bars as shown in the following example:[image]

My code currently:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-1,
  xmax=7,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=3.5,
  enlargelimits=true,
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  domain=0:2*pi,
  axis on top
]
%\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar interval, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
%\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar, bar width=1, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar=0pt, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=0:2*pi]{sin(deg(x))+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `bar width` to be equal to the distance between the samples. With a domain of `0:2pi` and 11 samples, set `bar width=2*pi/10` to get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-1,
  xmax=7,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=3.5,
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  domain=0:2*pi,
  axis on top,
  bar width=2*pi/10
]
%\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar interval, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
%\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar, bar width=1, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=gray, fill=gray!10, ybar=0pt, samples=11]{sin(deg(x))+2}\closedcycle;
\addplot[smooth, thick,domain=0:2*pi]{sin(deg(x))+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```