# No space between bars, symbolic x, multiple plots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to typeset a `ybar` chart with (maybe) several plots, symbolic x coordinates and a specified width so that bars have no space between them and also do not overlap. Each bar should have a node stating its height (y value).

This is similar to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57028/), except that the documentation says that `ybar interval` does not work well with `node near coords`.

So I am trying to derive `bar width` from the other parameters (ie. total width, number of x coordinates and number of plots). Setting it to `width/(nbCoord*nbPlots)` does not work.

First, one has to suppress the skip between bars with `bar shift auto={0pt}`. It also appears that the bars are shifted to the right to be centered with respect to the label. Thus (?), we have to provide for extra space with `enlarge x limits = {abs=XX}` where `XX` is half the width of a set of columns (that is `bar width` times the number of plots divided by 2).

The problem is to understand how this is taken into account for the whole width, so as to be able to deduce the `bar width` from the total specified width. With 3 plots, things seem to add up logically : setting `bar width=13mm` gives `XX=19.5mm`. Plotting 9 bars times 3 should give 9*3*13mm + 19.5mm = 370.5mm, and indeed, the following code aligns nicely

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=370.5mm, height=35mm,
              enlarge y limits = false, enlarge x limits={abs=19.5mm}, ybar, bar shift auto={0pt}, fill, hide y axis, nodes near coords,
              axis x line*=none, xtick=data, tick style={draw opacity=0},
              bar width={13mm},
              symbolic x coords = {{[0,2[},{[2,4[},{[4,6[},{[6,8[},{[8,10[},{[10,12[},{[12,14[},{[14,16[},{[16,18[}},
              %xmin={[0,2[}, xmax={dummy},
              %every node near coord/.append style={anchor=middle},
              x tick label style={font=\scriptsize}, node near coord style={font=\scriptsize}]

\addplot coordinates {
({[0,2[}, 0 )
({[2,4[}, 0 )
({[4,6[}, 4 )
({[6,8[}, 2 )
({[8,10[}, 11 )
({[10,12[}, 3 )
({[12,14[}, 6 )
({[14,16[}, 8 )
({[16,18[}, 2 )
};

\addplot coordinates {
({[0,2[}, 0 )
({[2,4[}, 0 )
({[4,6[}, 4 )
({[6,8[}, 2 )
({[8,10[}, 11 )
({[10,12[}, 3 )
({[12,14[}, 6 )
({[14,16[}, 8 )
({[16,18[}, 2 )
};

\addplot coordinates {
({[0,2[}, 0 )
({[2,4[}, 0 )
({[4,6[}, 4 )
({[6,8[}, 2 )
({[8,10[}, 11 )
({[10,12[}, 3 )
({[12,14[}, 6 )
({[14,16[}, 8 )
({[16,18[}, 2 )
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of above code]

However, taking the same formula for 2 series of bar gives `XX=13mm` and a width of 9*2*13mm + 13mm = 247mm, but there is slight overlap :

[image: same code with new values]

With only one series of bars, this gives `XX=6.5mm` and a width of 9*1*13mm+6.5mm = 123.5mm, and a greater overlap.

The computed value for `enlarge x limits` seems correct, as the first and last bar are each time perfectly aligned with the border of the plot.

But there is something to take into account for the whole width that I cannot see right now. What would it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar=0pt, bar width=10mm,
width=9*\numplots*\pgfplotbarwidth, height=35mm, scale only axis,
enlarge x limits={abs=0.5*\numplots*\pgfplotbarwidth}, enlarge y limits=false, 
hide y axis, 
nodes near coords,
axis x line*=none, xtick=data, tick style={draw=none},
symbolic x coords={{[0,2[},{[2,4[},{[4,6[},{[6,8[},{[8,10[},{[10,12[},{[12,14[},{[14,16[},{[16,18[}},
x tick label style={font=\scriptsize}, node near coord style={font=\scriptsize},
]
\addplot coordinates {({[0,2[}, 0 ) ({[2,4[}, 0 ) ({[4,6[}, 4 ) ({[6,8[}, 2 ) ({[8,10[}, 11 ) ({[10,12[}, 3 ) ({[12,14[}, 6 ) ({[14,16[}, 8 ) ({[16,18[}, 2 ) };
\addplot coordinates {({[0,2[}, 0 ) ({[2,4[}, 0 ) ({[4,6[}, 4 ) ({[6,8[}, 2 ) ({[8,10[}, 11 ) ({[10,12[}, 3 ) ({[12,14[}, 6 ) ({[14,16[}, 8 ) ({[16,18[}, 2 ) };
\addplot coordinates {({[0,2[}, 0 ) ({[2,4[}, 0 ) ({[4,6[}, 4 ) ({[6,8[}, 2 ) ({[8,10[}, 11 ) ({[10,12[}, 3 ) ({[12,14[}, 6 ) ({[14,16[}, 8 ) ({[16,18[}, 2 ) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with 27 bars of different heights and labels]

Comment: Thank you so much. I only have to reduce the height somewhat to take into account that the labels below are no longer included in it, but that is much simpler than fumbling with the width.